# Initializing values by memsets

Tags: c++, c++11

I have used an array as dt[100];
then,i have initialize the values like memset(dt,63,sizeof(dt));
then i have seen the value assigned in those array like 4557430888798830399.can i have the explanation?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define ll long long int
using namespace std;
ll dt[100];
int main()
{

 memset(dt,63,sizeof(dt));
 cout<<dt[0]<<endl;

}
```

Comment: The array elements are of type `long long`, `memset()` fills memory at the character level.

Comment: Use `for (size_t i=0; i<sizeof(dt)/sizeof(*dt); i++) dt[i] = 63;` instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

well, answers here are almost right.
the most flexible, correct solution is to use `std::fill` with `std::begin` + `std::end`

```
std::fill(std::begin(dt),std::end(dt),63);
```

1. you should use `std::fill` instead of `memset`, because `std::fill` is aware of objects and will call the correct assignment operation. `memset` knows only what a byte is (C vs C++).
2. `memset` fills bytes, `std::fill` fills any variable with any size
3. `std::fill` will call `memset` or `memmove` anyway if the variable size equals a byte size (yes, the standard library is not that stupid as we might think it is..)
4. `std::begin` + `std::end` "know" the size of a C array, so no erroneous stuff like `arr , arr + 100` which breaks the moment the array size is changed
5. `std::begin` + `std::end` work with C arrays and any C++ container which supplies `begin()` and `end()` methods (`vector , deque , list` etc). so without putting any effort, the code is *general* (the `sizeof` trick will not work for `std::vector`, for example).

as for why does the `long long` has such weird value, is because `memset` fills *every byte* and not every `long long`. 
so, assuming each `long long` is 8 bytes, memory wise, the `long long` after the `memset` looks like

```
byte
  |
  V
[63][63][63][63][63][63][63][63]
^                               ^
|        long long              |
```

and in binary :

```
0011111100111111001111110011111100111111001111110011111100111111 
//63 == 00111111, 8 bytes of each
```

which is :

```
4557430888798830399
```

(I deliberately did not go into endianess details in order not to complicate the subject too much)

Answer (score 4):

As per above answers, byte-level filling is the reason you get what you get. As an alternative to above suggestions, you could use this:

```
std::fill(dt, dt+100, 63);
```

The advantage here is that this is more likely to be optimized and thus quicker than manually looping over the memory (e.g. it could use SIMD vector instructions on x86_64 architectures)

Comment: hard coding the +100 is bad practice, the 100 figure might get changed in the declaration in some later refactoring, and there is the possibility of neglecting to change this line to reflect that. Also, it makes the fill call dependant on the data-structure of dt. std::begin and std::end abstract the data-structure and allows for greater flexibility - and since c++14 it works for arrays as well (except for dynamically created ones - which are bad practice in themselves - use std::vector for that!)

Answer (score 2):

As others have already pointed out, the `memset` copies 63 to each byte of the array. That is why your numbers are not what you expect. You should also try to avoid `memset` and `memcpy` in C++ and only use it when you are sure that the objects being copied are PODs or standard-layout types. Copying general C++ objects can be very problematic, and memsetting objects is a recipe for disaster.

An alternative to `std::fill`, which is fully ok, is to not use plain C arrays at all. Instead, use either `std::vector<long long>` or `std::array<long long, N>`.

To create a vector of 10 elements with value 63:

```
std::vector<long long> v(10, 63);
```

To create a statically allocated array of 10 elements with value 63

```
std::array<long, long, 10> a;
a.fill(63);
```

PS: try not to use `#define` for typedefs or constants or inline functions. C++ has type-safe replacements for most C constructs.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment by @Michael Burr, function `memset` sets the value of each `char` in the given block of memory, while each cell in your array is `long long`.

Alternative solutions:

```
for (size_t i=0; i<sizeof(dt)/sizeof(*dt); i++)
    dt[i] = 63;

for (auto& n : dt)
    n = 63;
```

Comment: ,i did not get the idea of setting the value of each char in given block...I have taken array of integer that's why char got me confused